# Supressing warnings about not awaited coroutines

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

My current setup: instantiate several UDP endpoints (`loop.create_datagram_endpoint`) and a aiohttp web server, then run them in separate processes using multiprocessing in separate event loops. So I have this piece of code:

```py
def run_in_loop(coroutine, loop):
    loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.stop)
        loop.close()
```

I use this function to create `multiprocessing.Process` and run given coroutine. Everything works fine and this architecture solves my problem, except when I terminate the program, I get:

```
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'TCPSite.start' was never awaited
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BaseEventLoop.create_datagram_endpoint' was never awaited
```

I've already tried to make exit cleaner, but this does not solve this problem.

Actually, the title is a bit misleading and I do not want to **suppress** these warnings but to solve the underlying issue somehow; I really do not know what are implications of this.

Comment: Silly question: do you call `TCPSite.start` somewhere in your code? If so, do you await it (or pass it to `create_task` or equivalent)?

Comment: @user4815162342, yep, I am calling `TCPSite.start` and `loop.create_datagram_endpoint` in main process, but I pass them in child processes and execute them there (using the function i included in question); everything works as expected except these warnings.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could pass coroutines from process to process, especially ones that include reference to the event loop.

Comment: @user4815162342, I issue a new event loop in order to create each long-running coroutine and pass the loop with the coroutine in child process.